# IOS 6 ScrollTo Bug in Ipad Mini[Tested]

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, ios6

I am using [ScrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) for scrolling `href` animation but when I tested in `Ipad Mini [IOS 6.0.1]` it working as buggy mean when as I have one nav bar which is `fixed` so when I click on any link so first it go to top of page and then comes down to specific link specified.It works fine in `Ipad IOS 5.0.1`